# Paypal response avscode (Master Card) is always "X"

Tags: php, magento, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm writing a module which prevent an user to checkout (with payment method Paypal pro, using Master Card, Visa, etc) if the zip code and address he provided not match those information in his card.

At first, I created 2 sandbox account (merchant and buyer) to check paypal's response. Here is the request I pushed to paypal sandbox:

```
array (
  'PAYMENTACTION' => 'Sale',
  'IPADDRESS' => '127.0.0.1',
  'RETURNFMFDETAILS' => 1,
  'AMT' => '30.75',
  'CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD',
  'INVNUM' => '100011074',
  'NOTIFYURL' => 'http://www.spacex.local/paypal/ipn/',
  'EMAIL' => 'abcsdf@yahoo.com',
  'CREDITCARDTYPE' => 'MasterCard',
  'ACCT' => '5110925307034185',
  'EXPDATE' => '112024',
  'CVV2' => '185',
  'ISSUENUMBER' => NULL,
  'ITEMAMT' => '22.00',
  'TAXAMT' => '0.00',
  'SHIPPINGAMT' => '8.75',
  'BUSINESS' => NULL,
  'FIRSTNAME' => 'fgdgdfg',
  'LASTNAME' => 'dgdgdfg',
  'MIDDLENAME' => NULL,
  'SALUTATION' => NULL,
  'SUFFIX' => NULL,
  'COUNTRYCODE' => 'US',
  'STATE' => 'AK',
  'CITY' => 'sdfsdfsdf',
  'STREET' => 'asdfasdfsdf',
  'ZIP' => '12345',
  'PHONENUM' => '12345679',
  'SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE' => 'US',
  'SHIPTOSTATE' => 'AK',
  'SHIPTOCITY' => 'sdfsdfsdf',
  'SHIPTOSTREET' => 'asdfasdfsdf',
  'SHIPTOZIP' => '12345',
  'SHIPTOPHONENUM' => '12345679',
  'SHIPTOSTREET2' => '',
  'STREET2' => '',
  'SHIPTONAME' => 'fgdgdfg dgdgdfg',
  'METHOD' => 'DoDirectPayment',
)
```

And here is the response

```
array (
  'TIMESTAMP' => '2015-05-26T09:03:56Z',
  'CORRELATIONID' => '181a742e9983a',
  'ACK' => 'Success',
  'VERSION' => '72.0',
  'BUILD' => '16770825',
  'AMT' => '30.75',
  'CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD',
  'AVSCODE' => 'X',
  'CVV2MATCH' => 'M',
  'TRANSACTIONID' => '5SN572797S568915L',
)
```

The information I need is `AVSCODE` with value "X" which means "Street address and 9-digit postal code match." (see https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/AVSResponseCodes/#avs-response-codes). However, my buyer sandbox account doesn't even have any address and zip code (since I can't find anywhere to save address and zip code to my account), why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cards, and therefore AVS verification, are not real in the sandbox.

AVS is a check that the card issuer makes against the billing address on the card, not a check that PayPal makes against PayPal account addresses (note that PayPal accounts don't even a "billing address" per se). No (real) card, no (real) issuer, no (real) AVS.

For how to do negative testing (including AVS) in the sandbox see:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_error-conditions/

(Note that this is also the top google reference for "paypal sandbox avs test")

Comment: Oh wow, this is not a good way paypal provide us to test. But thank you so much, my hero!